# I need to solve differential equation 4th order to a difference equation using central differencing method?

Tags: derivatives

I know the below equation is the solution but don't know how to obtain it using central differencing scheme. I tried solving it using 2nd order central differencing but still not able to get the below solution

$$F^{(4)}(x) = \frac{ F(x) - 4F(x + h) + 6F(x + 2h) - 4F(x + 3h) + F(x + 4h) }{ h^4} $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: I tried solving it using using second order central difference eqtion but still cant able to get the above solution.

Comment: Then edit your question, adding to it your attempt.